# Why is it possible to add text inside the head section

Tags: html, html-head

Why does the text inside a `head` section of a HTML page get rendered in the DOM?

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element) the head section should do the following:

> The HTML  element provides general information (metadata) about the document, including its title and links to its scripts and style sheets.

If you place some text inside the head section of the page, it will get placed in the body section of the rendered webpage. Isn't this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text is not valid in the `head` tag.

The error correction of the browser moves the text from the `head` to the `body`

[4.2.1 The head element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element)

> **Content model:**
>   If the document is an iframe srcdoc document or if title information is available from a higher-level protocol: Zero or more elements of `metadata` content, of which no more than one is a `title` element and no more than one is a `base` element.
>   *Otherwise:* One or more elements of `metadata` content, of which exactly one is a `title` element and no more than one is a `base` element.

Comment: @DavidSnabel there are also rules defining how incorrect html should be handled. I think it was defined with the _whatwg_ but i can't find it right now.